# How do I attach the bullet to moving sprite

Tags: javascript, html, css

So far, I've created the box which can move is you press the up, down, left, & right arrow keys.  But now, I want to attach the bullet to the box so that every time I press the spacebar, it shoots a bullet.  I'm just kind of lost as to how to go about doing this (the keycode for spacebar is 32).

gameTime.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WOMP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gameTime.css">
</head>     
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
<div id="bullet"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gameTime.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

gameTime.css

```
#bullet {
    background: #8A2BE2;
    width: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 340px;
}
```

gameTime.js

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;

context.rect(xPos,yPos,50,50);
context.stroke();

function movement(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        xPos += 5;
    } 

    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        xPos -= 5;
    }

    if(e.keyCode == 38) {
        yPos -=5;
    }

    if(e.keyCode == 40) {
        yPos +=5;
    }

    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    context.rect(xPos,yPos,50,50);
    context.stroke();
}

document.onkeydown = movement;
```

Comment: Every spacebar-press you should create new `rect` with it's own coordinates, speead and direction, and recalculate it's with `setInterval`.